# Soft Commit and Hard Commit in SOLR

Tags: solr

This is the default configuration in solr core for soft commit and hard commit.

```
<autoCommit> 
       <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime> 
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
     </autoCommit>


     <autoSoftCommit> 
       <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime> 
     </autoSoftCommit>
```

Now , my understanding is that if I comment out the section for soft commit then near real time search should not work.But it is not happening so.Even if I comment out soft commit section I am able to retrieve the doc in a second.
Also  where is the value set for the variables  solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime & solr.autoCommit.maxTime?

Answer (score 1):

After commenting out those lines you should reload the core or restart solr. In that way only the hard commit will take place (note that if you have few docs the hard commit is very fast)

About the other question: those are system properties, that is, properties you can specify in the command line. For instance, if you run Solr like this:

> java -Dparam1=3 ....

In solrconfig.xml you can use

${param1} to get the value of that property. Solr lets you also specify a default value (15000 and -1 in your snippets) in case such parameter hasn't been set

Answer (score 0):

Are you retrieving the doc with a query or via the real time get handler? Soft commits (or hard commits with opensearcher = true) make the document visible in searchs, but when using the realtime get handler you can always get the document via it's uniqueid provided that you have the update log enabled (it's on by default).

Comment: I am using the select Handler to query the result and not the real time get handler

Comment: how are you indexing, xml post or dataimporthandler? are you using commitwithin or something like that? are new documents or updates? how are you testing that the document is visible in one second?

Comment: I have around 100 records in Json format , which I index through post.jar.After indexing if I query the record I am able to fetch it

Comment: The most probable cause is that post.jar is commiting the results. You should index just a document with curl and test if it's visible.